# PHPMailer variable in addadress

Tags: php

I have a PHP mailer function set up to send a mail to a customer that purchases a file. IT works perfect if I use a static emailaddress in the AddAdress method. But if I use a variable it doesn't get sent.

```
function sendEmailToClient($name, $address, $postcode, $city, $email, $which, $orderid, $downloadlink){
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    // $mail->isSMTP();
    // $mail->Host = 'localhost';
    $mail->setFrom('email@email.com', 'My Store');
    $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient





    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Thanks for your order';
    $mail->Body    = '<body>
    <p>Order:</p>
    <p>Order ID: '.$orderid.'</p>
    <p>Book: '.$which.'<br />
    Name: '.$name.'<br />
    Address: '.$address.'<br />
    Postal code: '.$postcode.'<br />
    City: '.$city.'<br/>
    Email: '.$email.'</p>
    <p>Download: '.$downloadlink.'</p>
    <p>Have fun!!</p>
    </body>';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the variable doesn't work. I checked the input from the function to see if the email is actually a valid email, and that is the case. But it's not working with the variable.

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: So start debugging. See if there is actually something in `$email`. See wwhat your error is. See hwat gets set differently when you don't use the dynamic address.

Comment: If the variable is not set inside the function you need to use the `$GLOBALS` variable eg: `$GLOBALS['myEmail']`

Comment: Where you instantiate your PHPMailer, pass $mail->SMTPDEbug = 4; See if that spits outs more debugging output. Are you passing a list of e-mails? If so, that might not work. You need to call the AddAddress function once for each E-Mail address you want to send to.

Comment: There is something in $email because the body of the message gets filled with the email variable. I call the function from another script where the $email is passed in as a parameter. It's not a list, it's a single emailaddress